# Update Word table based on Excel data

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I have a Report Template created in MS Word. Now, I have some data in Excel spreadsheet which needs to be merged with the report template. I explored the `Mail Merge` functionality in MS Word, where I can create multiple reports. But, as I see the function is only static and can only work, if the data is uniform for each row, which I don't. 
Sample data in Excel is,
[image: Excel Data]

[image: Excel Format 2]

The data is shown in word in the following format,
[image: Word Format]

```
Sub CopyRowToRC()
Sheet2.Range("A:B").Clear
i = 1
j = 2
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Sheet1
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
For i = 1 To LastRow

With Sheet2
LastRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
If i > 1 Then
LastRows = LastRows + 2
End If
End With

If j <= LastRow Then
Sheet1.Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy
Sheet2.Range("A" & LastRows).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=True
Sheet1.Rows(j).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy
Sheet2.Range("B" & LastRows).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=True
j = j + 1
End If
Next
Sheet2.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
WordUp
End Sub


Sub WordUp()
On Error Resume Next
Dim WdObj As Object, fname As String
fname = "File Name"
Set WdObj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WdObj.Visible = True

With Sheet2
LastRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Sheet2.Range("A1:B" & LastRows).Copy

WdObj.documents.Add
WdObj.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
With WdObj
    .ActiveDocument.Close
    .Quit
End With
Set WdObj = Nothing
Sheet2.Range("A:B").Clear
Sheet1.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The above code helps me to create a table for each row for the second Excel format attached, in Word by just converting columns into rows. But there are data to be pasted outside the table too.

Comment: Can you clarify more exactly what you're actual question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this appears to be a standard document format - something you'll be re-using - the first step is to create a Word document with the basic "structures". Type in and format all the static text that will never change. Use the Insert/Links/Bookmark command in the Ribbon to set "targets" for the dynamic data coming from Excel (or any other source).

Save this as a *template* (dotx file format). Change your `WdObj.documents.Add` line of code to pick up this file path. A new document will be created based on the template and will contain the static text plus the bookmarks. Be sure to set it to a `Word.Document` object:

```
Dim wdDoc as Word.Document 'or As Object if you don't have a reference to the Word library
Set wdDoc = WdObj.Documents.Add("filepath")
```

Target the bookmarks you defined in your code*:

```
Dim rngTarget as Word.Range
Set rngTarget = wdDoc.Bookmarks("NameOfBookmark").Range
rngTarget.PasteExcelTable False, False, False

Set rngTarget = wdDoc.Bookmarks("DifferentBookmark").Range
rngTarget.Text = Sheet1.Range("A2").Value2 'for example, to get the name
```

When you're done, don't forget to *save* the document before closing...

```
wdDoc.SaveAs "filepath"
wdDoc.Close
wdObj.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set wdObj = Nothing
```

Also, use error handling correctly. As it stands, you won't see any errors, but you need to see them. Otherwise you won't know if or why your code is failing. Remove `On Error Resume Next` from your code - this only makes sense if you're using `GetObject` to pick up a running Word application. In such a case, this is followed immediately by `On Error GoTo 0` which turns errors back on.

*Note: you can assign directly to a bookmark, but if you need the range for something else, such as formatting, better to do it in two steps. To assign directly:

```
wdDoc.Bookmarks("NameOfBookmark").Range.Text = "abc"
```